# How to implement single sign-on using kerberos authentication in azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, kerberos-delegation

Using Azure Active Directory When i am applying single sign on for my web application i am able to do the Password-based single sign-on successfully.

But when i am doing with Integrated Windows Authentication(for kerberos authentication mainly), i am not able to configure it. i am very confused.

Can anybody guide me how to enable kerberos authentication for web application.
or please send me any example links how to set kerberos authentication for web applications.

Thanks!

Comment: AAD doesn't support Kerberos. if you want to authentiation with kerberos, you'd better use [AAD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) to integrate your on-prmise AD with AAD.

Comment: thanks for your response Wayne.. Do you have any examples on how to integrate it?

Comment: Hi @Sunil , I think there are some examples in the documentation I posted in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use Azure AD with Kerberos for Windows Integrated Authentication there was a comment about AADConnect, which has some offerings, especially if you use ADFS for Federated sign-ins.  There is also the [Azure App Proxy with KCD support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-sso-using-kcd)

[image: Auth Diagram]